# Gradle sync failed: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

[its showing that the system cant find the path, but I don't know which particular path it is referring to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSbD4.png)

I am trying to install android studio but now I am getting this error

Comment: Have you mentioned the path to your Android SDK in android studio?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the path to Android SDK in android studio

> File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location

Usually, your SDK will in this path:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Attaching Screenshot for reference:
[image]

Comment: Yup, this worked. I was trying to install the sdk on my external ssd as it was filling up my C drive.