# Android studio error "Gradle sync failed: The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile-application

i am new for android studio i am facing the following error in my first
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvJH5.png)helloworl project  "Gradle sync failed: The system cannot find the path specified" how o solve this issue , thanks.

Comment: Have you added the path to your Android SDK in android studio?

Comment: If you haven't done that, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65102274/gradle-sync-failed-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified) solution.